# I want to work with live chat in SignalR and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, signalr

I get the following error when trying to send a message with `SignalR`:

> TypeError: $scope.chatHub.server.SendMessageToAdmin is not a function

The error occurs in this function:

```
vm.sentUserMsg = function (message) {
    var userName = 'Guest';
    $scope.name = 'Guest'; // holds the user's name
    $scope.message = ''; // holds the new message
    $scope.messages = []; // collection of messages coming from server
    $scope.chatHub = null; // holds the reference to hub
    $scope.chatHub = $.connection.chatHub; // initializes hub
    $.connection.hub.start(); // starts hub
    $scope.chatHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
        var newMessage = name + ' says: ' + message;
        $scope.messages.push(newMessage);
        $scope.$apply();
    };
    var producttype = '1';
    $scope.chatHub.server.SendMessageToAdmin(userName, message, producttype);
    $scope.message = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to hazard a guess that you have a casing issue for the method "SendMessageToAdmin".

I assume that you're following common conventions and that the SendMessageToAdmin method on the server that lives in your Hub class starts with a capital "S". Note that when SignalR generates a Javascript proxy, it changes the casing of method names to match Javascript conventions. Therefore, the method name within your javascript code should be camelCased. Example:

```
$scope.chatHub.server.sendMessageToAdmin(userName, message, producttype);
```

The relevant docs are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#how-to-call-server-methods-from-the-client).

Specifically, here's the quote:

> Pass in a camel-case version of the method name on the Hub. SignalR
>   automatically makes this change so that JavaScript code can conform to
>   JavaScript conventions.